# Unable to build blender

Tags: python, compiler-errors, compilation, blender

I am trying to build `blender` so that I can [use it directly from python](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) and was going through [this tutorial](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake) and I got stuck on the very first `make` command giving me

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibsUnix (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARY PYTHON_LIBPATH
  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR)
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, with the system python installs (3.4.3 and 2.7.6). I am expected to specify manually these environment variables (if they are that)? Or it's something else? If the former, what are the standard paths for these?

Comment: I have the same problem. I compiled python into the /usr prefix from source and blender still can not find it. The blender developers are simply incompetent - otherwise they would have a build system that works just fine with. But hey, that's what you get for transitioning into cmake ... easy options like GNU autoconfigure had, are no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve your issue

```
sudo apt-get build-dep  blender
```

similar compile time dependency problems for other applications can be solved by doing this `build-dep` trick

By cherry picking from the list of packages above cmd wants to install, you probably need just these :

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev libpython3.4-dev
```

although allowing the `build-dep` cmd to run will jack up otherwise disabled features you may want in blender

enjoy

Comment: It installed these python related packages, but this did not resolve the issue: `python3-all python3-all-dev libpython3-all-dev` :(

Comment: No - this has not solved the issue in the slightest. You just delegated towards debian-specific workaround. The proper solution would be to have blender find python irrespective of which distribution.

Answer (score 6):

For compilation, you have to point to Python3:

```
cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/bin/python3.4m -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.4m ..
```

Comment: fwiw, the GNUMakefile will also forward the `BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS` to cmake, like so in bash with python 3.8 ex: `BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS=-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/bin/python3.8\ -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.8/ make`

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't finding the python files then you will need to tell it where they are.

If you have checked out the current master then it would be looking for python 3.5 as this has recently been setup to be the default for the next release, you can still set it to 3.4 for now as I don't think any 3.5 specific code changes have happened yet. If you downloaded a release tarball then it should be looking for 3.4 (unless you have an older source copy)

Answer (score 1):

[this website](https://wiki.blender.jp/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Dependencies_From_Source)
claims that the following syntax will "re-define [all PYTHON_* variables] based on your Python prefix"

```
cmake ./ ../blender -U PYTHON* -D PYTHON_ROOT_DIR=/opt/my_python
```

and i think this should be the equivalent of passing these settings into blender 3.0's makefile

```
BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS=-U\ PYTHON\*\ -D\ PYTHON_ROOT_DIR=$PWD/my-path-to/Python-3.9.9/ make
```

...

but i still get

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibsUnix (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARY PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
  PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR)
```

so idk, maybe this is an obsolete doc

Comment: ps, blender uses cmake's standard python discovery (at time of writing ~blender 3.0), so python specific blender make issues are not blender specific.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the [python development libraries](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-dev)

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

??

Comment: No, I have it for both python and python3.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**  Python3.10 ( and future versions I assume ) are included in the precompiled libs but the update fails to get new files often (an svn issue).  If you aren't making any changes in ../lib then you are safe to use revert instead:

```
cd ../lib/linux_centos7_x86_64
svn revert --recursive .
```

*don't miss the trailing period.*

You shouldn't need to do anything else.

I'm leaving my original solution below:

---

**My distro ( Devuan ) doesn't yet offer python3.10. I compiled and installed it in a custom directory so as not to affect existing python installations.**

**Find the python version you need and download it from
https://www.python.org/downloads/**

**Expand it in a working directory ( ok to delete later ):**

```
tar -xf Python-3.10.8.tgz
cd Python-3.10.8
```

**now configure python to build with custom paths ( here I'm using  ~/blenderpython )**

```
export set BLENDERPYTHONDIR=/home/`whoami`/blenderpython

./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$BLENDERPYTHONDIR
make -j 4 
make install
```

**Add required packages:**

```
cd $BLENDERPYTHONDIR/bin/;  
./pip3 install numpy;
./pip3 install requests;
./pip3 install zstandard;
./pip3 install cython;
./pip3 -vvv list   # to see installed and where.
# i.e. all installed in ~/blenderpython/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

**Now go to your blender source.. in home dir?**

```
cd ~/blender-git/blender/
```

**and try building again specifying your new python**

```
BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS=-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$BLENDERPYTHONDIR/bin/python3.10\ -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$BLENDERPYTHONDIR/lib/libpython3.10.a\ -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$BLENDERPYTHONDIR/include/python3.10/ make full
```

*note there are two backslashed spaces in the command above.*

*note PYTHON_EXECUTABLE and PYTHON_LIBRARY point to files.  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR points to... a dir.*